# Objective-c: UIView animate + block + recursion

Tags: objective-c, recursion, block, objective-c-blocks

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    typedef  void (^myBlock)(int );

    @interface ViewController ()

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (IBAction)blockTest:(id)sender
    {
        [self blockRecursion:0];
    }

    - (void)blockRecursion:(NSInteger)n
    {
        __weak myBlock __block block = ^(int bn)
        {
            NSLog(@"%d", bn);
            if(bn < 10)
            {
                [self getData:block num:++bn];
            }
        };

        block(0);
    }


    - (void)getData:(myBlock)block num:(NSInteger)bn
    {
        self.testView.alpha = 1;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            self.testView.alpha = 0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            block(bn);
        }];
    }

    @end
```

Run Crash：
error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file

```
__weak myBlock __block block = ^(int bn);
//Changed to 
myBlock __block block = ^(int bn);
```

Show a Warning : Capturing 'block' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that there is no strong reference to the block object. `block` is a weak reference. So after the statement where the block object is created, the block object can potentially be deallocated, which will set the `__weak` variable `block` to `nil`. Invoking a block with a `nil` block pointer crashes.

When you remove the `__weak`, you create a retain cycle -- the block retains a strong reference to itself.

What you need is two variables, one strong and one weak. The block captures the weak one. The one the block captures needs to be `__block` to reflect the assignment after the block was created.

```
    myBlock blockStrong;
    __block __weak myBlock blockWeak;
    blockWeak = blockString = ^(int bn)
    {
        NSLog(@"%d", bn);
        if(bn < 10)
        {
            [self getData:blockWeak num:++bn];
        }
    };
```

Comment: Won't referencing self inside this block lead to a retain cycle here as well?

Comment: @danielbeard: no, because nowhere does `self` retain this block. where are you seeing a "cycle"?